# How to download Black Ops 2 DLC that is not showing up in Xbox Live Store?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I want to buy all the Black Ops 2 DLC on the Xbox 360. But when I searched the Store for the DLC Packs, the Packs simply were not there. So I tried the Game itself, and that didn't work either. However, when I checked the Store via PC, the DLC Packs were there and ready to be downloaded. How is this possible? and more importantly, how can I buy the DLC on the 360 if it is not showing up in the store?

Comment: Nit sure why you cant find it on the console to purchase, but purchasing content on microsofts website should give make the content available to download in-game, on your console. If it's still not available to download after purchasing, that is strange.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I was buy the DLC on PC with my gamertag, and I was log on to my 360 with the same account. Would the DLC start downloading automatically?

Comment: probably not automatically but when you look at the DLC on the console, it should indicate that you own it, or that uts ready to install. But yes, that is the idea, ownership of content is independent of the platform on which it was purchased (as long as you buy the 360 dlc, and not the PC dlc, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this happens, power cycle your xbox (Turn it on and off three times in a row) then launch BO2, after that go into zombies or multi player. Connect to XBL Servers then go back to zombies/ multiplayer menu, you should see XBL Sys Link Options, look at the bottom you should see STORE, they're in there.